# 3.5mm with audio and microphone in pc

Tags: audio, microphone, 3.5mm

So, I am planning on buying a new headset and the 3.5mm jack wire is both audio and microphone in one. I am unable to find out whether my case and/or motherboard supports this kind of wire.

Q1: What are these 'two-in-one audio/mic' 3.5mm jack cables called?

Q2: Which specification would I have to check (now, and in the future) to check for support?

Comment: If you only have one 3.5mm receptacle, it will support input and output. Otherwise you will have 2 which will be labeled.

Comment: @Xavierjazz They are labeled, pink and green one on motherboard, and symbols for mic and audio on front of case. Will not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. These connectors are called TRRS (tip-ring-ring-sleeve), 4-pole jacks, or combo jacks. Their pinouts vary from maker to maker, but as I assume your future headphones to be generic, they should be compatible with common devices.

A2. You can check your motherboard's documentation. If you have audio jacks both for microphone and the headphones, the 4-pole plug is probably not supported. (The headphones would still work without the microphone.)

If there's only one jack, and it has a label depicting a pair of headphones with, well, a microphone, then the microphone will work.

Comment: The connector is called a ["TRRS" (Tip-ring-ring-sleeve) Phone Connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio))

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 There actually is a lot of names.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's the official one.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yeah, reflected in the answer.